# Как получить следующий аргумент в BASH?

Tags: bash, shell

Хочу в цикле присвоить `_P=arg3`, если до него стоял `-x`.

```
#foo.sh arg1 -x arg3

for n in $@
do
  if [ $n == "-x" ]; then
     _P=$(n++)    # _P необходимо присвоить arg3 
  break
  fi
done
```

Но не присваивает. Как правильно присвоить следующий аргумент?

Comment: @Andrew F, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Изучите, как работает это:

```
while [[ $# >0 ]];
do
if [ $1 == "-x" ]; then
      shift 
    _P=$1    # _P необходимо присвоить arg3 
      echo $_P
fi
shift 
done
```

**UPD**

```
INDEX=1
for n in $@
do
  ((INDEX++))
  if [ $n == "-x" ]; then
     _P=${@:$INDEX:1}    # _P необходимо присвоить arg3 
     echo "$_P"
  break
  fi
done
```

Comment: А без shift? Он же все сдвигаетю Просто мне потом еще раз необходимо обрабатывать эти аргументы.

Comment: не вижу смысла. Загнали все аргументы в переменные, дак дальше ими и пользуйтесь. 
>А без shift? 

UPD без shift